googleVRForUnity_1.200.1 gives me error in unity sdk 2022
When I import GoogleVRForUnity_1.200.1 into my Unity 2022 SDK, I encounter numerous errors related to the deprecated Daydream feature. Can anyone assist me in resolving this issue?
My goal is to develop a mobile VR application that doesn't require physical controllers. I want users to have the ability to move within the application without the need for physical game controllers.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You should try the official Google Open Source Cardboard SDK instead.
https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart
